# iOS loading table data with nested request

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, http, alamofire

I am working with a `UITableView` which contains an image and some labels.
The text is loading from one server and the image is downloaded from another server. The image `URL` is dependent on the text value response but I have to show them in one cell. What I have to do is combine those data after they have loaded and to then to show them.

What could be the right approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine response of two requests using DispatchGroup:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
var text: String?
var image: UIImage?

group.enter()
requestText(completion: { response in
    text = // extract text from response
    group.leave()
})

group.enter()
requestImage(completion: { response in
    image = // extract image from response
    group.leave()
})

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
    let textWithImage = (text, image)
    // show data in table view
})
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. should i call the notify inside  `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->` function??

Comment: No. You can do it in method where you request data.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply display the textual data first than as soon as a image is downloaded you can than map that image to the textual data by having some common id in both the responses and reload that particular cell . In this way the user will be able to see the textual data and after some milliseconds the images will also show up nicely.